# What prepositionshould I use "in/on/at"? Is it correct to use a preposition here?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition should I use in this sentence: "He played 2 games in the last - 20th day". In this sentence last day means that this is the 20th day of the season and it's his last season in football. Should I write **in the last day** or **on the last day**"? Would it be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems a bit confusing here. 20th is the ordinal number, and can be used in this situation:

The last time he played football was on *April* the 20th. Or
The 20th of + *month name* ( more formal );

But given that you intend to say something different, here is my suggestion, and my version:

> He has only played two games **over the first 20 days of *this/the*
> season** so far, though it *is/may be* his last.

I hope I got your question right.

Comment: Let's put this way: "**He played 2 games in the last day of a season**". Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: @poker59 It should read: *on the last day of the season*.